# regex expression to remove more than on : or

Tags: javascript, regex

```
let string = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9:.]/g, "");
```

Hey guys so I have the following line and it works great to remove everything that is not a number or a : or a . but what if I want to remove everything that is not a number but also remove all but the first occurrence of a . and a : and also not allow them to do both at the same time. for example this would be valid `16:9` and so would this 16.93 but not 16::9, 16...9 or 19:0.0 Thanks

Comment: You're best off using string manipulation, but with V8 you can use `(?<!^[^:.]*)[:.]+`

Comment: I cant seem to get it to work can you send me a fiddle or an example?

Answer (score 0):

#### Using regex

This will only work in some browsers (V8 engine + ) because it uses a variable length lookbehind.

```
(?<!^[^:.]*)[:.]+
```

The above regex works as follows:

- `(?<!^[^:.]*)` negative lookbehind ensuring the following does not match

  - `^` assert position at the start of the line
  - `[^:.]*` match any character that is not in the set `:.` any number of times
- `[:.]+` match one or more of any character in the set `:.`

```js
s = ['16:9','16.93','16::9','16...9','19:0.0']
r = /(?<!^[^:.]*)[:.]+/g
for (x of s) {
  console.log(x.replace(r,''))
}
```

---

#### Using string manipulation with regex

This method splits the string after the first location of any character in the set `:.`, then replaces all characters in the set `:.` after that split location, then rejoins the two strings together.

```js
s = ['16:9','16.93','16::9','16...9','19:0.0']
for (x of s) {
  m = /[:.]/.exec(x)
  y = x.substring(0,m.index+1) + x.substring(m.index).replace(/[:.]+/g,'')
  console.log(y)
}
```

Comment: Your first snippet gets a syntax error on Firefox 70

Comment: @Nick as expected, no full V8 support as I mentioned

Comment: This is cool but it doesn't seem to take effect until after I do a space in the form field

Comment: @codernoob7 that's likely an issue with your event call

Comment: @Nick see [lookbehind assertions - browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Browser_compatibility)